# How to modify the theme of material component without using xml?

Tags: android, material-components-android, materialbutton

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.Life.Red" />
```

We can modify the Theme by using `android:theme="***"`.

### But I wan to modify the Theme in Java/Kotlin code.

```
MaterialButton button= ...
button.setTheme(...)
```

Unfortunately, there is no `setTheme` method...

Comment: A theme can only be applied as whole during `View` instantiation. After that, you'll either have to handle modifying everything manually, as available methods allow, or replace the `View` with a new instance created with the desired theme (which you would do with a `ContextThemeWrapper`, btw). AFAIK, Material Components has not changed that, nor has otherwise added anything to help with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the theme to specific view, then you have to add the material style in that view's "theme" or "style" attribute according to your need.

But if you want to apply the theme to the whole activity then you can do it by

```
setTheme(R.style.AppThemeCustom);
```

Add this line before setContentView() in your activity.

Define that theme in theme.xml

```
<style name="AppThemeCustom" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

You said that you want to apply the Theme to the view only.

Then you can use the theme attribute If your view contains multiple views & you want to apply the theme to all the child.
If have only one view, say you have a button, then you can use style attribute in that view.

NOTE : You can use 2 options here : Predefined themes or your Custom themes (make it by yourself in themes.xml as I mentioned in the answer)

You can find more about themes & styles here:

Comment: I just want to set the Theme to the view.